# Python : parse string to sub string for searching

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

My web site run on [gae](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview), I want to implement a input-tag-box like tags input box in SO, but [search](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview) on gae required user enter whole word for match.
Example `hello world` required user enter `world` or `hello` for result `hello world` and I want to when user enter some word like `he` or `hel` then result `hello world`.

I looking for a function for parse a string into multi sub string (implemented in python)

Ex: `hello world` --> `he hel hell hello wor worl world`.

Any other solution are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You have given what you want, but not a problem. What have you tried, how didn't it work? Did you get an error or incorrect results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension and slicing:

```
>>> strs= "Hello world"
>>> [y for x in strs.split() for y in (x[:i] for i in  xrange(2,len(x)+1)) ]
['He', 'Hel', 'Hell', 'Hello', 'wo', 'wor', 'worl', 'world']
```